# mysql friend system, index, foreign key, prim key

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys

I am making a friend system for my website. I am thinking of making only 2 rows, add an index on each of them and making them foreign keys to the `users` table `id` column. I would like them deleted if either of the users are deleted. There will then be a record for each user.

```
user_id
friend_id
```

1. Question: Do you see any reason at all to include a primary key?
2. Question: Will the foreign keys function as described above, when setting them to cascade?

If you have any other advice or column suggestion, i would like to hear that too (: (I will not need to know when the friendship started)

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you need a primary key. In this case it might be best to use a compound primary key on both columns.  Without it, your queries will be MUCH slower than they should be and you wouldn't be able to enforce uniqueness of the friend pair.

The other thing you should consider is whether the friend relationship is a one-way relationship or two-way.  In other words, do you need to be able to look up the friend relationship in either direction (starting with either user).  If so, you will probably need to insert two rows into that table for each friend relationship.

With regard to the cascading delete, you would want to make sure you set up such a cascade on both columns so that is a user was deleted in the users table, it would delete all rows in the relation table where that user is either the user or the friend.

Comment: Good answer. But im having some trouble seeing what the use would be if i added a column called id which was primary key, when i would never lookup the table from that id. How could it then improve performance? I do have a index on the user_id which is what i would "reference" in the where clause of my select statement. Not that i have a problem with adding the id, i would just like to understand why.

Comment: @JensAhlstenHerlevsen I am not suggesting you add an autoincrement primary key column. I specifically mentioned a compound primary key using these two columns. You could enforce uniqueness on the pair and is you are always looking up by `user_id` and this is the first column in the index, you have no need for a separate index on user_id by itself. You should pretty much always have a primary of some sort on every table.

Comment: ALTER TABLE friends ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id, friend_id); Would that  also imply that the combination of the 2 columns will be unique?

Comment: @JensAhlstenHerlevsen That is correct. The uniqueness is enforced on the pair of values, which is what you want here.

Comment: Ok. And to round it up, just to be sure: With the primary key created on the 2 tables, the index on each of them is redundant?

Comment: @JensAhlstenHerlevsen You mean with a primary index on the two columns? You would have indexes on those two columns if you specify a foreign key. But there is no need for any other index.